# How back two UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My application has four steps (View1, View2, and finally View3 View4) in which the user must pass before finalizing the process. At the end there is a back button. However when I click back the app sends the user to View3 (At this point he is in View4).

The problem is how to return to View1 with a simple click the back button?

I have two views that inherit from UIViewController and the other two that inherit UITableViewController

To create a new view I use the code above:

`SelectSubOptionsViewController * selectSubOpt;
    selectSubOpt = [[ SelectSubOptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectSubOptionsViewController" bundle:nil]
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];`

```
[self.view addSubview: selectSubOpt.view];
```

And to remove a view I use the code above:

`-(IBAction) btnBack:(id) sender {`

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                       forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Tanks a lot for any answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UINavigationController to manage your screens -- do a push to put up each view, then do a pop to root controller to get back to the beginning.  I think it is more suited to your task here.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Tanks Alan! But for I use a instance of UINavigationController for go back to root view, can I use chain of UIViewController? I think to create  a instance of UINavigationController e pass this instance to the view2 and view3 and view4 (of course putting this views in chain). In view4 I would use this instance to go back to the root view (view1). Is correct this approach?

Comment: Yes, the UINavigationController allows you to manage a chain of UIViewControllers, that's exactly what its good for.  You would "push" your views 2, 3, 4 and then you can do a pop to root from 4 to get back to view 1.  Good luck!